# Why some Android code works on previous API level than it should?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lint

I'm developping an Android application which, among other things, uses the method toLongArray from java.BitSet. As can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/BitSet.html#toLongArray%28%29), this method was introduced in Android API level 19, Android 4.4. Lint in Eclipse correctly warns me about that, because my minSdkVersion is 10, but I can configure it so it doesn't complain.

When doing so, I could build by project and run it: in Android 5.0 it works, in Android 2.3 (API level 10) it doesn't, but surprisingly, in Android 4.0.3, 4.1.2, 4.2 (which are below API level 19) it works like a charm, even though it shouldn't work. The same happens even if I set min/target sdk to 15 (Android 4.0.3).

The same happens for Object.hashCode, for example, and I can't figure out why it works.

Comment: it's not officially there but it is in fact there and hidden http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/BitSet.java#724 I guess so they could start to bring in new features without having to support them officially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this surprised me a lot.

I went to their repository to see actually what the hell is that. So I found that they add some methods but hide it in the documentation using @hide javadoc annotation until it's fully tested or until they remember to unhide it.

> @hide When applied to a package, class, method or field, @hide removes
>   that node and all of its children from the documentation.

so to know the truth the [toLongArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/BitSet.html#toLongArray%28%29) method was actually added in a [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/27a5b793cc7ae8a72ba2f767214a828becdc64cd) more than 3 years and 10 months ago and actually they unhide it 1 year, 7 months ago in this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/8ffa0b68c9fd3f722bee2bcd94b1d38151a0791d).